# Qual o tipo variável correspondente de timestamp (SQL Server) no C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, conversão-de-tipo, dataannotations

Tenho um campo no banco de dados (SeqAlteracao) do tipo `timestamp` e preciso mapeá-lo para o C# (Entity Framework).

Qual o tipo correspondente no C# para esse tipo no banco?

```
 public **Tipo** SeqAlteracao { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o tipo `byte` com anotação de `TimeStamp`

```
 [Timestamp]
 public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Olha esse [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/TimeStamp-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) para entender melhor.

Comment: Esse totorial demostrou bem o uso, era exatamente o que precisava, pois usar DataAnnotations.

Comment: ah o S é minusculo [Timestamp]

Comment: Coloquei minusculo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O normal e que parece mais óbvio seria usar o [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0), afinal o objetivo de ambos, grosso modo, é o mesmo, é apontar um ponto no tempo. Cada um com uma representação diferente, mas o dado é o mesmo. E quando falamos em dados para serem processados a representação não importa, isso só interessa quando vai dar uma saída. Então leia um [`timestamp`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) e jogue em um `DateTime`.

Ou não faça isso, porque o objetivo específico do tipo `timestamp` do SQL Server na verdade é para fazer versionamento e não exatamente para guardar um ponto no tempo. Então só use assim mesmo se a modelagem do SQL Server foi feita errada e usaram o tipo errado.

Os tipos corretos no SQL Server quando a intenção é guardar um horário é o [`datetime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) e o [`datetime2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). Na verdade, até isso não é perfeito, já que as semânticas de cada um dos dois e o tipo do C# não batem.

Ser a intenção for guardar um versionamento mesmo, use um [`long`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Há quem até prefira criar um tipo próprio.